# c++ "error: no matching function for call to" when count in a set

Tags: c++, function, dictionary, set, matching

I'm implementing a map using a set and a Tuple class which i made as an exercise and i keep getting this error: `error: no matching function for call to 'std::set<Tuple<int, char>, std::less<Tuple<int, char> >, std::allocator<Tuple<int, char> > >::count(Tuple<char, int>&)`

this is my code:

```
        template <class K,class V> class Tuple
{
private:
    K* mKey;
    V* mValue;
public:
    Tuple(const K& key, const V& val)
    {
        mKey = &key;
        mValue = &val;
    };

    Tuple(const K& key)
    {
        mKey = &key;
    };
    const K& getKey()
    {
        return *mKey;
    };
    const V& getValue()
    {
        return *mValue;
    };
    void setKey(const K& key)
    {
        mKey=&key;
    };
    void setValue(const V& val)
    {
        mValue=&val;
    };
    bool operator< (Tuple<K,V>& t)
    {
        return *mKey<*t.mKey;
    };
    bool operator== (Tuple<K,V>& t)
    {
        return *mKey==*t.mKey;
    };
};

template <class K,class V> class map
{
private:
    set<Tuple<K,V> >* mTupleMap;

public:
    map()
    {
        mTupleMap = new set<Tuple<K,V> >;
    };

    void insert(const K& key,const V& val)
    {
        Tuple<V,K> tmp(key,val);
        if(mTupleMap->count(tmp)!=0)
        {
            typename set<Tuple<K,V> >::iterator it;
            it=mTupleMap->find(tmp);
            (*it).setValue(val);
        }
        else
        {
            mTupleMap->insert(tmp);
        }
    }
    const V& getValue(const K& key)
    {
        set<V,K> tmp(key);
        if(mTupleMap->count(tmp)!=0)
        {
            typename set<Tuple<K,V> >::iterator it;
            it=mTupleMap->find(tmp);
            return (*it).getValue();
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<int,char> mapIntToChar;
    mapIntToChar.insert(1,'a');
    mapIntToChar.insert(2,'b');
    mapIntToChar.insert(1,'c');
    cout << mapIntToChar.getValue(1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea what's the problem or how to solve it so I'll like to get some help.

Comment: Did you include `string.h` and `string`?

Comment: `const` issue perhaps?

Comment: this is what's include:#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

Comment: Storing pointers in the tuple is inviting trouble for dinner and telling it to bring all its facebook friends. None of your map entries will be valid.

Comment: @OfirAbramov **You're using `std`, but *not* including `string` and `string.h`**? Include them..

Answer (score 4):

Your `tmp` is `Tuple<V, K>`, but your `set` contains `Tuple<K, V>` and you have `operator <` only for type `Tuple<K,V>`.

Comment: WOW I'm more stupid then what i was thinking haha thanks it did solved this problem but now it yeild this error: "stl_function.h|237|error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'|" when the "<" is called, i did changed it to be:      "return (*mKey) < t.mKey;". any ideas?

Comment: operator< getting as input a reference to Tuple<K,V> not a pointer, so i call it's members with "." and the dereference is not nessesery. isn't it?

Comment: @OfirAbramov if you are trying to compare values - you should dereference pointers. If addresses you shouldn't dereference.